# How to create table from multi computations from data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to apply simulation calculation to evaluate RMSE. I have ten data frames without missing values `df1, df2, df3, ..., dm10`and each of them contains three variables e.g. `df1$x, df1$y, df1$z`. Then, I generate some missing rates from the original data frames ('''df''') to create `dm1, dm2, dm3, dm4, ..., dm10`. I ran multiple missing imputations using `mice` package to estimate the missing values using `dm1, dm2, dm3, ..., dm10` then I generate complete data frames which are `pm1, pm2, pm3, pm4, ..., pm10`. I want to run a loop function to create `rmse` for each variable from each data frame set, all results should be collected in one table using the following:

the first row is the answer of:

```
library(DMwR)
actuals <- df1$x[is.na(dm1$x)]
predicteds <- pm1[is.na(dm1$x), "x"]
regr.eval(actuals, predicteds)
```

the second row is the answer of:

```
actuals <- df1$y[is.na(dm1$y)]
predicteds <- pm1[is.na(dm1$y), "y"]
regr.eval(actuals, predicteds)
```

the third row is the answer of:

```
actuals <- df1$y[is.na(dm1$z)]
predicteds <- pm1[is.na(dm1$z), "z"]
regr.eval(actuals, predicteds)
```

the fourth row is the answer of:

```
actuals <- df2$x[is.na(dm2$x)]
predicteds <- pm2[is.na(dm2$x), "x"]
regr.eval(actuals, predicteds)
```

.
.
.
.

the last row is the answer of:

```
actuals <- df10$z[is.na(dm10$z)]
predicteds <- pm10[is.na(dm10$z), "z"]
regr.eval(actuals, predicteds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad,
Put your two sets of dataframes into two lists

```
dfList = list(df1, df2, df3, ..., dm10)
dmList = list(dm1, dm2, dm3, dm4, ..., dm10)
```

Turn this code:

```
actuals <- df1$x[is.na(dm1$x)]
predicteds <- pm1[is.na(dm1$x), "x"]
regr.eval(actuals, predicteds)
```

Into a function which runs a single case

```
run1case <- function(df, dm, xyz){
  <your code here>
}
```

Run `run1case` with test inputs.  E.g., call

```
run1case(df2, dm2, "x")
```

until it seems solid.  If a run takes more than, say, a minute, consider building small, test versions of `df` and `dm`.

Add another function

```
runSlice <- function(df, dm){
   map_df(c("x","y","z"), ~ run1case(df, dm, .))
}
```

Again, test this with single values of `df` and `dm` until you get a good execution - which will be 3 runs together.

Finally, run the whole thing

```
rezult <- map2_df( dfList , dmList, runSlice)
```

## NOT RUN